# New to Java Generics - why is there a Type for a return type of void in Generics?

Tags: java

I am new to JAVA generics below the return type is void but why are they giving the type .

```
public static <U> void addBox(U u,List<Box<U>> boxes){
    Box<U> box = new Box<U>();
    box.setT(u);
    boxes.add(box);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<U>` isn't a return type. It is declaring that `U` is a generic class that will be used in the method's parameters and in the method body.

You can read more about generic methods and their syntax [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html).

Comment: Thanks, I can under stand now.

Answer (score 0):

is defined for input parameters and not return type. It is declared here like this because  is defined at method level and not class level like class Abc

thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest reading  [Effective Java,](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321356683) . Author Joshua Bloch has given pretty good illustrations in Chapter 5.